# fetch data using ajax on date selection with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to fetch data on change of date using date type,have fetched data from database. But after that, the data that is fetched contains button to be clicked. On click of button fetch the data again.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="date" name="gdate" id="gdate" onchange="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"/>
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function makeAjaxRequest(dateval) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {dateva: dateval},
                url: "fetchbills.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#showresult').html(data);
                    $('#det').on("click", function () {
                        var no = $(this).val();
                        makeAjaxRequest2(no);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        function makeAjaxRequest2(billno) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {bno: billno},
                url: "fetchbilldetail.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#showresult').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        $("#gdate").on("change", function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            makeAjaxRequest(id);

        });
    </script>
    <div id="showresult">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**fetchbills.php**

```
<?php

include("./config.php");
$dt = $_REQUEST["dateva"];
$sql = "select bill_id,order_id from bill_master where order_date='$dt'";
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("error");
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row[0] . "<br>";
        echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='det' value='" . $row[1] . "' onclick='get(this.value)' /></form>
    <div id='show'></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

using the above I get order id.The id's are displayed in form of buttons.
On click of buttons I want to get the details of order id.but what sholud I do I can't understand.

I am new to ajax and don,t know how to do it.

here the the code for order details

```
<?php

include("./config.php");
$det = $_GET["bno"];
//echo $det;
$sql = "SELECT m.old_order_id,m.old_order_amount,l.item_id,l.old_order_quantity,i.item_name from old_order_master m,old_order_list l,item_list i where m.old_order_id=$det and m.old_order_id=l.old_order_id and l.item_id=i.item_id";
//echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[4] . "</td><td>" . $row[3] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You got any error message?

Comment: no error but I didn't get the another data i.e order details on button click.

Comment: Can anyone please give suggestion,have to complete it as soon as possible.

Comment: Use type post in ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following changes in your **`fetchbills.php`** file and let me know

```
<?php

include("./config.php");

$dt = $_REQUEST["dateva"];
$sql = "select bill_id,order_id from bill_master where order_date='$dt'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("error");

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo $row[0] . "<br>";
        echo "<form method='post' action=''>"
            ."<input type='button' name='det' value='" . $row[1] . "' onclick='makeAjaxRequest2(".$row[1].");' /></form>"
            ."<div id='show'></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: hey the data is outputed,but it disappers within a blink and the html page i.e the 1 page with date picker without any value is reloaded back.without anything.

Comment: Are you sure you've used above entire code for `fetchtbills.php`? For page not to refresh I've added `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: sorry missed that thing.thanks a lot for your help. Its working. :)